# Spring Security Concurrent Session : failed to make "max-sessions" field configurable

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a requirement to allow Concurrent-session control in my web app and make configurable field "max-sessions". My configuration looks like:

```
<security:session-management>
    <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="${maxConcurrentSessionsCount}" session-registry-ref="sessionRegistry" expired-url="/handleInvalidatedSession.gs4tr"/>
</security:session-management>`
```

As you can guess, in "services.properties" file there should be "maxConcurrentSessionsCount" field which clients would set by their will.
But I'm getting next warning in Intelij:

```
"attribute 'max-sessions' on element 'security:concurrency-control' is not valid with respect to its type, 'positiveInteger'".
```

I successfully configure many others things, like "token-validity-seconds" and "remember-me-cookie" in "remember-me", etc.
Any idea how to solve a problem? Search couple of days over internet for help, but failed.

EDIT:
In "services.properties" is configured:
"maxConcurrentSessionsCount=2"

On start application, it throws next error:

```
No, it doesn't. It throws next ERROR on starting app:
```

017-09-14 15:46:47,724 ERROR [org.gs4tr.projectdirector.service.context.ContextLoaderListener][localhost-startStop-1][user:] - 
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 75 in XML document from class path resource [org/gs4tr/foundation/modules/webmvc/spring/applicationContext-security-default.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 75; columnNumber: 72; cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '${maxConcurrentSessionsCount}' is not a valid value for 'integer'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.gs4tr.projectdirector.service.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4811)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5251)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)

Comment: So you're getting a warning, but does it work? Do you have the `maxConcurrentSesionsCount` parameter defined somewhere? Is IntelliJ IDEA aware of it?

Comment: @Kayaman See EDIT in question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition of max-session attribute:

```
<xs:attribute name="max-sessions" type="xs:positiveInteger">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>
The maximum number of sessions a single authenticated user can have open at the same time. Defaults to "1".
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:attribute>
```

As you can see, the type of the attribute is `positiveInteger` and you are not allowed to use SpEL.

SpEL (e.g. getting property value) is an string and in some cases you are allowed to [use SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch07s04.html):

> A property or constructor-arg value can be set using expressions as shown below